# Does this video show an ISIS car bomb sent flying by an explosion?

Tags: terrorism, video, isis

The [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3038067/Incredible-footage-shows-ISIS-suicide-bomber-s-car-explode-MID-AIR-vehicle-blasted-skywards-seconds-driver-s-IEDs-detonate.html) and [Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/isis-suicide-bombers-car-gets-thrown-sky-high-before-exploding-mid-air-10178183.html) have reported on this video, which claims to show an ISIS car bomb being sent flying by an explosion. The original YouTube video can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFxfWupuxbE):

A screencapture of the video is shown below:

[image]

However, both sources have reported different reasons the car was sent flying. The Daily Mail claims it was a roadside bomb, while Independent claims it was a landmine.

Is this video genuine, and does it show an ISIS car bomb as reported?

Comment: I wonder if "roadside bomb" and "landmine", rather than contradicting each other, might be two different journalists' attempts to dumb down, I mean, *simplify* a car having driven over and triggered an IED (improvised explosive device).